Scraping Instagram Hashtags fails after few runs
I'm working on a Python script to scrape Instagram posts by hashtag. It worked for few runs, and then it stopped working due to this error:
{
    "message": "Please wait a few minutes before you try again.",
    "require_login": true,
    "status": "fail"
}


I keep getting it despite using proxies and different user agents.
Here is a relevant part of the code:

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 ' \
                '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'
class IGScraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.session.headers = {'user-agent': user_agent}
        self.session.cookies.set('ig_pr', '1')
        self.session.proxies = {
            "http": "...",
            "https": "...",
        }
        self.rhx_gis = None

    def scrape_hashtag(self, hashtag, end_cursor='', maximum=10, first=10,
                      detail=False):

        try:
            params = f'{{"tag_name":"{hashtag}","first":{10},"after":"{end_cursor}"}}'
           
            response = self.session.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/'+f'graphql/query/?query_hash=ded47faa9a1aaded10161a2ff32abb6b&variables={params}').json()
            print(response) 

You can simulate this more easily by creating a get request to:
https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=ded47faa9a1aaded10161a2ff32abb6b&variables={ "tag_name":"hello","first":10,"after":""}

The response is the error from above.
How can I fix this?
